# Ignore all value other than 'English' word

Tags: python

Write a function called letter_count(filename) that accepts a single parameter containing the name of a file.  Your function should read the contents of the text file, and calculate the number of times each English letter appears in the file. The function should print a list of (character : count) pairs to the standard output.

You may define additional “helper” functions as you wish. Any character that is not an English letter should be ignored. The case should be ignored (so both ’a’ and ’A’ count as the letter ’a’). Report the output with lower case letters.  The letters should be sorted into standard alphabetical order and should be printed in the format letter, then a space, then a colon, then a space, then the frequency.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YrTv.png)

I'm struggling to get the result same as the image, which I supposed to get only alphabet and ignore other value. However, I'm able to ignore only number. Below is where I up to:

```
def letter_count(filename):
f = open(filename, 'r')
content = f.read().lower()
data = content.split()

mydicts = {}
for letter in data:
    for i in letter:
        count = mydicts.get(i, 0)
        mydicts[i] = count + 1

mydicts_list = mydicts.keys()

for letter in sorted(mydicts_list):
    print(letter, ':', mydicts[letter])
```

Comment: Does your problem have anything to do with the part about sorting?

Comment: Requested from question, but I have solved this particular part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting work for you:

```
import string
from collections import Counter

with open(filename) as f:
    char_counts = Counter(c for c in f.read().lower() if c in string.ascii_lowercase)
    for c in sorted(char_counts):
        print(c, char_counts[c])
```